# Autoregression model

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am using AR model in Python. The code is:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR  
import numpy as np  
signal=np.loadtxt("secular.txt")      
ar_mod = AR(signal)    
ar_res = ar_mod.fit(4)    
print AR(signal)    
print ar_res
```

As I know, the ar_res shoule be an array which is detrended of the original one. But, the result of print is this one:

```
<statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR object at 0x7f9224f88d10>    
<statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ARResultsWrapper object at 0x7f9225542b10>
```

I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Try print(ar_mod.params) or print(ar_res.params).

Comment: It seems that I am not familiar enough with this package. And I cannot find any useful movie on youtube to learn it.

Comment: Try this to start with, you will certainly find other resources as well https://machinelearningmastery.com/autoregression-models-time-series-forecasting-python/

Comment: Thank you very much